# SEO Best Practices for Portfolio Website

Tags: seo

I have a portfolio site show-casing design and development work. Each portfolio piece has its own URL. For example, if I've designed a site for Joe's Pizza, and my site is mysite.com, then Joe's Pizza will have it's own URL at www.mysite.com/portfolio/joes-pizza .

For each portfolio piece, the title is the title of the business for which I designed or developed the project. Obviously, it's important to my SEO for these to be indexed. However, what I don't want to happen is to have these indexed in a way that disrupts the client's SEO. For example, I don't want someone to Google local pizza shops and have my site pop before Joe's Pizza. I do want my site to pop for web design searches.

What is best practice for how to handle these portfolio pieces? Should I exclude them from being indexed? Should I permit indexing and follow a specific title/description format? I don't want to hurt clients' SEO and I'm not certain which is the best way to proceed in a way that still permits my own site to rank.

Thanks in advance.